# casperjs and a/b testing

Tags: automated-tests, phantomjs, casperjs

i have a signup.js test that automates signing up for my web app (obviously). we're currently a/b testing a new flow that takes you to a different page ('.com/signupa' vs '.com/signupb') and i'm wondering what the best way to reflect this in my test.

**options:**

- use `evaluateOrDie` and make it die at .com/signupb (this seems dumb)
- flesh out test for .com/signupb and make it go that route if it hits that test (is this possible?)  something like..

  ```
  casper.waitForResource("classic.png",
     function success() {
        this.echo('on the old signup flow ');
        <continue with regular signup test>
    },  
    function fail() {
        this.test.assertExists("classic.png");
        <do something else>
    });
  ```

any other ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: I went to post an answer, but realized I don't know what you mean by "reflect this in my test"? (It seems you can just call '.com/signupa' vs '.com/signupb' directly if you wanted to make sure each gets tested.)

Comment: @DarrenCook sorry, shoulda been more clear. the a/b test happens after you submit the signup form. so the flow goes /join -> fill out some fields -> hit Submit -> then you either get /signupa or /signupb. which means i can't really call them directly. i guess i'm wondering if, on submit, there's a way to make casper evaluate which page i'm getting (a or b) and then run tests accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to hide some information in each of your pages, so you can cleanly switch on them. E.g.

```
<span id="version1"></span>
```

vs.

```
<span id="version2"></span>
```

Then, after submitting the form:

```
casper.then(function(){
  if (this.exists('#version2')) {
    testNewSite(this);
    } else {
    testOldSite(this);
    }
  });
```

But detecting on something you already know is only in one of the pages, like the "classic.png" you show in your question, is also fine.  (It just feels a little more brittle: the web development team can break your tests by renaming that image, or putting an image with that name in the new version, etc., etc.)